# BusyBox Help, ip Command

Tags: android, linux, terminal

I'm using a Google phone running Android, and I need to figure out how to use the terminal's 
'ip' command.

I found out that Android uses BusyBox in its terminal, but I can't find any help or tutorials or any information regarding it other than the basic information given in the terminal help. Can anyone point me to a site that would give me more information on how to use the commands, or tell me how to use the 'ip' command if you are familiar with it?

Thanks.

Comment: Android doesn't actually use busybox.

Comment: Hmmm, since this is the second comment I've seen that says this, I'm starting to get confused.

Ohhh, whoops. Forgot to mention that I have CyanogenMod flashed as a custom ROM. Never mind. :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://www.busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html#item_ip) is the BusyBox usage information, for starters, and [here](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ip) is a full Linux man page. Note that the BusyBox implementation can be expected to be "bare bones", i.e. not as fully featured.

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly what I was looking for. I didn't realize it was a standard Linux command.

Answer (score 1):

Busy box is just an implementation of the standard Unix command line utilities any man page on ip will work.  You should be able to google man ip.  Also busybox's website has a full manual for what it supports.

Answer (score 1):

`ip` command does not seem to be available on the phone, and the device does not use BusyBox (it does use toolbox for commands such as `cat`, `chmod`, etc though).

Depending on what you are trying to achieve, you may consider using `route`, `netcfg` or `ifconfig`.

This answer applies to the official Cupcake branch of Android OS and Google Android Dev Phone 1.

If you are running some custom distribution, then regular Linux [`ip`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ip) command from [BusyBox](http://www.busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html#item%5Fip) may apply.

Comment: I'm not sure what phone you are talking about, the Android series running cupcake 1.5 Android OS should all have the ip command and definitely has busybox on it. Running the "busybox" command returns the entire list of busybox commands available. 

My phone is rooted, so it might be blocked on a non-rooted phone, not sure.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that I have the Cyanogen Mod ROM custom loaded. He probably added busybox with the custom rom.

Comment: I am talking about main and official branch of Android OS which you can browse at http://android.git.kernel.org/ and see it yourself that there is no BusyBox. Prior creating my answer, I double-checked my beliefs both in the code and on the Google Android Dev Phone 1.
If you are running some other code, then your question should be different.